# Web.config file for the contents and Scripts folder not copied while doing an msbuild to get the build package

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web-config

I am working on a asp.net mvc2 project which has Contents folder containing images,css files and Scripts folder containing all the js libraries and files used in the project. I have a web.config file containing the code for enabling caching for the contents present within the Contents and Scripts folder as mentioned below:

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--Caching-->
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" cacheControlCustom="must-revalidate"/>
      <!--<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Tue, 31 Dec 2030 12:00:00 GMT"/>-->
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am using msbuild to get a package ready for deployment. I see the package is built successfully containing the MSI which I install in the server. After installing the MSI I see that there is no web.config present within the Contents and Scripts folder in the server.

I tried setting Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always in the properties section of the web.config file but still I don't see it in the Contents and Scripts folder in the server.

Can anyone help me to fix the issue?

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume you are building your MSI with the Visual Studio Web Setup Project. In that case, you also need to make sure your extra web.config files are included in the "File System" tab view of your installer project. Normally those would be part of "Content Files".

Comment: Any useful links related to the process and moreover in case I add the web.config file how can I be sure that it is going to be added to the Contents folder after the MSI is executed.

Comment: When you have your setup project selected in Solution Explorer, a few special icons will show up in that panel; the second one is called "File System Explorer". When you choose that, a new window will show up for you to view the files/folders that will be created. When you choose the "Web Application Folder", you probably already have "Content Files from <project>" there - by right-clicking on it and selecting "Output" you will be able to see all files that will be installed.

Comment: More details on different install techniques are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2kt85ked(v=vs.100).aspx)